# How to search and get rid of this character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, unicode

```
Bulmaca-Zeka Oyunu<200f>
```

I have a lot of strings in a text file, and I noticed that one has this <200f> char. I want to find all entries that have this char and remove it. But in Vim I can't find it by searching '<200f>' using the search string '<200f>'. Probably it is one char not 6 individual chars.

In Python or VIM, how to remove or search them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those literal characters in angle brackets are how Vim handles some problematic unprintable characters. They are quite puzzling at first but they are really easy to figure out because they simply spell out the character's hexadecimal code.

In this case, `<200f>` is the literal representation of [U+200F](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm), which you search like this:

```
/\%u200f
```

So, if you want to get rid of the occurrences of `<200f>` in the current buffer, all you have to do is:

```
:%s/\%u200f//g
```

See `:help \%u`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find it in `vim` because you're not searching for the correct string.
Check your `vim` documentation: angle brackets are meta-characters.  Simply escape them, and remove the undesired strings.

```
:%s/\<200f\>//g
```

Comment: No. Not only `<` and `>` are not meta-characters but OP doesn't have the string `<200f>` in their buffers and your search pattern would match `200f` anyway, not `<200f>`.

Answer (score -1):

In Python you could perhaps use string replacement :

```
line_of_text = "Bulmaca-Zeka Oyunu<200f>"
print(line_of_text.replace("<200f>", "")
```

Output :

```
Bulmaca-Zeka Oyunu
```

Comment: `"<200f>"` this is a string of 6 characters while the OP has one character with this representation.